# Searching lists in dictionaries in python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of users, which contains 2 lists as a value for every key.
And I have a dictionary of itemlists which contains lists as values.

```py
dict_users = {
'User1': [['item10', 'item3', 'item6'], ['item1', 'item7', 'item8']], 
'User2': [['item10', 'item6', 'item2'], ['item2', 'item10', 'item5']],
'User3': [['item2', 'item9', 'item3'], ['item8', 'item3', 'item1']]
}

dict_items = {
'itemlist1': ['item10', 'item3', 'item1', 'item7', 'item8', 'item4'],
'itemlist2': ['item2', 'item5', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item6'],
'itemlist3': ['item9', 'item6', 'item1', 'item7', 'item2', 'item4']
}
```

Now I would like to find for each user in dict_users an itemlist from dict_items that contains (at least) 2 items from the first list and 2 items from the second list of the lists that are values of the users in dict_users.
So in this example User1 would be paired with itemlist1. It would be nice if this was in a new dictionary like so:

```py
dict_pairs = {
'User1': 'itemlist1'
}
etc
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just calls for [`set intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```py
dict_pairs = {}

for user, lists in dict_users.items():
    for itemlist, items in dict_items.items():
        items = set(items)
        if all(len(items & set(lst)) >= 2 for lst in lists):
            dict_pairs[user] = itemlist
            break
```

For each user we iterate through the item lists. Then, we check if [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) sub-lists of the user have an intersection greater (or equal) to 2 with the items list. If so, we add that to the final dict and move on.

For your example dicts, this will give:

```
dict_pairs = {
'User1': 'itemlist1',
'User2': 'itemlist2'
}
```